# Excel - Vlookup & Countif?

Tags: excel

I have a series of data items where I have

> `Date, Name of Person, Class Name, RSVP, Attended`

And I am trying to create a report where I have the the # of times that a Person Attended where the RSVP is Yes.

I have this right now but it's just giving me every instance of where the value is Yes in RSVP..

```
A3 contains the person's name
The data is is T3:W135
The Column for RSVP is W

=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP($A3,'Data - Week 1'!$T$3:$W$135,1,0)),0,COUNTIF('Data - Week 1'!$W$3:$W$135,"Yes"))
```

Comment: Why not just use a Pivot Table?

Comment: I did end up doing that but there is more that I want to do with the report than just this one item. There are vlookups to categorize the type of class that was attended as well. Was hoping to just be able to program it, update the data and the report spits out nicely without any manual tallying.

Comment: That's certainly sounds doable.  Whether it would be easier with VBA, Power Query, or formulas would depend on your precise specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Use COUNTIFS():

```
=COUNTIFS('Data - Week 1'!$T:$T,$A3,'Data - Week 1'!$W:$W,"Yes",'Data - Week 1'!$X:$X,"Yes")
```

I am assuming that you have `Yes`/`No` in the Attended Column

Comment: I ended up doing a Pivot Table for this piece of data and I replaced all the No with nothing so that it would count it correctly in the table.